# Django serializer queryset and retrieve foreign key values

Tags: python, json, django

I want to get the username value related to the user field within the TWEET model.

Here are the two models that I am working with:

```
class Tweet(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    user = models.ForeignKey('USER', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='USER_ID')  # Field name made lowercase.
    content = models.CharField(db_column='CONTENT', max_length=45)  # Field name made lowercase.
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(db_column='TIMESTAMP')  # Field name made lowercase.
    like_counter = models.IntegerField(db_column='LIKE_COUNTER')  # Field name made lowercase.
    parent_tweet = models.ForeignKey('self', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='PARENT_TWEET', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.True

class User(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    username = models.CharField(db_column='USERNAME', max_length=45)  # Field name made lowercase.
    email = models.CharField(db_column='EMAIL', max_length=100)  # Field name made lowercase.
    password = models.CharField(db_column='PASSWORD', max_length=45)  # Field name made lowercase.
```

function to serialize queryset:

```
#returns a queryset of first 5 tweets in order of most recent
tweet_data = Tweet.objects.filter(user_id__in = following_ids).filter().order_by('-timestamp')[:5]
tweet_data_json = serializers.serialize('json', tweet_data, fields=('id','user__username','content','timestamp','like_counter','parent_tweet'))
return tweet_data_json
```

Within serialize() I use user__username In hopes of returning the username referred to by the user value within the tweets table, however this does not appear in my json data?

Comment: Are you talking about serializers and viewsets?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Django Natural Keys serialization for this process.You need to update your `User` model as:

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    username = models.CharField(db_column='USERNAME', max_length=45)  # Field name made lowercase.
    email = models.CharField(db_column='EMAIL', max_length=100)  # Field name made lowercase.
    password = models.CharField(db_column='PASSWORD', max_length=45)  # Field name made lowercase.

    def natural_keys(self):
        return self.username
```

Then when you call the `serialize` method, you need to set the `use_natural_foreign_keys` as `True`. Example:

```
tweet_data_json = serializers.serialize('json', tweet_data, use_natural_foreign_keys=True, use_natural_primary_key=True)
```

For reference you can check [django-natural-keys](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/serialization/#natural-keys)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the documentation. :)

Answer (score 0):

By default, Django does not provide such values in serializer. But you can try to override it to get the desired data. For example you can override [json serializer](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/serializers/json.py) like this:

```
from django.core.serializers.json import Serializer

class CustomSerializer(Serializer):

    def end_object(self, obj):
        for field in self.selected_fields:
            if field == 'pk':
                continue
            elif field in self._current.keys():
                continue
            else:
                try:
                    if '__' in field:
                        fields = field.split('__')
                        value = obj
                        for f in fields:
                            value = getattr(value, f)
                        if value != obj:
                            self._current[field] = value
                    else:
                        self._current[field] = getattr(obj,field)

                except AttributeError:
                    pass
        super(CustomSerializer, self).end_object(obj)
```

Now you can use this serializer as following:

```
serializers = CustomSerializer()
tweet_data_json = serializers.serialize(tweet_data, fields=('id','user__username','content','timestamp','like_counter','parent_tweet'))
```